# Setting "fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache" = true vs creating new instance of hdfs file system

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In case of Multi-threading application, if we use `FileSystem.get` and close the file system, other threads will get `FileSystem closed` exception.

If we disable the cache, it will not be static implementation of `FileSystem` objects i.e new file system object will be created everytime.

I am trying to find out the difference between `FileSystem.newInstance` and disabling the cache.

What would be the difference in terms of memory/performance?